# write to file an object of an odd type? in java

Tags: java

The resulting cyphertext from my project is an object consisting of 3 fields: two byte arrays and a Point on elliptic curves in Affine coordinates. Because of this Point type field I cannot use serialization so i cannot write the cyphertext in a file. What can I do to save (write in a file or any other solution) the cyphertext and be able to use it (read it from file) in decryption afterwards?

Comment: Why can't you use serialization?

Answer (score 1):

If your errors are because your Point class isn't serializable, you can probably get by by implementing that interface, which generally means you do nothing beyond that.  The default implementation works in most cases.

```
 public class MyPoint extends Point implements Serializable {
 ...
 }
```

Then use MyPoint in your code, or at least the parts of the code that write the file.

If Point isn't serializable, however, it may be for a reason.  If this is the case you'll have to add actual methods to MyPoint do the serialization, and probably the deserialization too.